# Please help to convert String to timestamp in hive

Tags: date, hive, timestamp, hql, sqldatatypes

Please help me to convert string to timestamp.

source data is in Excel

[image]

Need to convert it as below timestamp

> 2019-12-15T16:35:53.663-04:00

I tried with.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('12/15/2019 21:18','mm/dd/yyyy'),'YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00-00:00')
```

Got below error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Both source pattern and target pattern are wrong in your query. See [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for reference. Also initial string does not contain the timezone and it is not clear how are you going to derive it as -04:00. In such case it will be UTC timezone used, you can convert to other timezone using from_utc_timestamp.

Timestamp string conversion demo:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('12/15/2019 21:18','MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

Result:

```
2019-12-15T21:18:00.000+0000
```